# SQL FOR XML - Outputting data as Elements and Attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to export some data from a database in a particular XML format specified by the customer. The XML I produce will be processed by a 3rd party application as an import

The customer has requested data formatted on each person like so:

```
<Person>
    <Item ExportId="Ethnicity">99</Item>
    <Item ExportId="LastName">SMIFF</Item>
    <Item ExportId="FirstName">Arfur</Item>
    <Hospital>
        <Item ExportId="PrimarySite">C7</Item>
        <Item ExportId="RecordNum">C7</Item>
    </Hospital>
</Person>
```

My current SQL

```
SELECT     "Item/@ExportID"= 'Race1',  
           Race , 
           "Item/@ExportID" = 'sex', 
           Sex,
           "Pateint/Condition/Item/@ExportID" = 'dateOfDiagnosis', 
           DxDate
FROM    TABLE
```

the above SQL is close, but it gives me

```
<Patient>
    <Item ExportID="Race1"/>
    <Race>09</Race>
    <Item ExportID="sex"/>
    <Sex>2</Sex>
    <Condition>
        <Item ExportID="dateOfDiagnosis"/>
    </Condition>
    <DxDate>20190906</DxDate>
</Patient>
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS and its version.